# map of sets initialization (Go)

Tags: go

Below Golang code gathers a set of nutriments for each recipe, based on an input of this form:

```
# applepie
- flour
- apple
- egg
# pizza
- flour
- cheese
- egg
- tomato
```

It complains at (2) of `assignment to entry in nil map`.

But why ? Each "submap" is howhever initialized with the `make` at (1) ?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    nutriments := map[string][]string{
            "flour":{"sugars"},
            "egg":{"protein", "fat"},
            "tomato":{"water", "viamins"},
            "cheese":{"calcium", "protein"},
            "apple":{"sugars", "fiber", "vitamin"} }
    total := make(map[string]map[string]bool)
    f := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    currentRecipe := ""
    for f.Scan() {
            Line(f.Text(), currentRecipe, nutriments, total)
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
}

func Line (line, currentRecipe string, nut map[string][]string, tot map[string]map[string]bool) {
    if foundrec, _ := regexp.MatchString("^# [[:graph:]]+", line); foundrec { // Begin recipe
            currentRecipe := line[2:]
            fmt.Println("---------", currentRecipe) // update current
            tot[currentRecipe] = make(map[string]bool) // <== INITIALIZE SET (1)
    }
    if foundnut, _ := regexp.MatchString("^- [[:graph:]]+", line); foundnut { // New ingredient
            nutri := line[2:]
            tot[currentRecipe][nutri] = true   // <===== HERE (2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have read one more time in the book "The Go Programming Language", 4.1 to 4.3, but still don't see the problem after 3 hours of debugging.

Comment: This is possible if `foundrec` is false, but `foundnut` is not, so the map is never initialized.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Sure, but input is designed to always have a 'recipe' line before 'ingredient' lines. Sample is given.

Comment: Try printing `currentRecipe` before that second `if` statement in `Line`. I think you'll find it's usually unset.

Comment: If you are expecting the code in `Line` to set the `currentRecipe` declared in `main`, then that's your problem. `currentRecipe` is always an empty string on the way in to the `Line` function.

Comment: @larsks You are rigth, thanks! But why isn't the incoming string updated ??

Comment: @BurakSerdar The string is initialized **before** the loop. It would be modifyed in the Line function ?

Comment: All args are pass-by-value. So a copy of `currentRecipe` is passed to the `Line` function. Easiest way to fix it is to return `currentRecipe` from Line, and reassign in `main`

Comment: If input is designed to have it or not. Program design is still not nice. You should always anticipate someone "misusing" your program. Then they will fault you. I know it wasn't the issue, but I wouldn't pass this in a code review. Maybe just make the map before anything else, or do something else to prevent this issue from ever occurring. You could also exit with an error code, if the input wasn't right and don't keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in comments, problem was lying in the update mechanism for currentRecipe. string was passed by value.

Here is correct code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    nutriments := map[string][]string{
            "flour":{"sugars"},
            "egg":{"protein", "fat"},
            "tomato":{"water", "viamins"},
            "cheese":{"calcium", "protein"},
            "apple":{"sugars", "fiber", "vitamin"} }
    total := make(map[string]map[string]bool)
    f := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    currentRecipe := ""
    for f.Scan() {
            currentRecipe = Line(f.Text(), currentRecipe, nutriments, total)
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
}

func Line (line, currentRecipe string, nut map[string][]string, tot map[string]map[string]bool) string {
    if foundrec, _ := regexp.MatchString("^# [[:graph:]]+", line); foundrec { // Begin recipe
            currentRecipe = line[2:]
            fmt.Println("---------", currentRecipe) // update current
            tot[currentRecipe] = make(map[string]bool) // prepare set
    }
    if foundnut, _ := regexp.MatchString("^- [[:graph:]]+", line); foundnut { // Begin ingredients list
            nutri := line[2:]
            tot[currentRecipe][nutri] = true
    }
    return currentRecipe
}
```